# How can I explain to a friend's child that I don't like sleepovers without parents?

Tags: conflict-aversion, children, denmark

I have a female friend, whom I've been friends with for over 20 years.
Her 12 year old boy (I'm his godfather) is very fascinated by my virtual reality gaming setup at home, and very often and very insistently asks me if he can come play and spend the night so he can play more the following day.

I'm a single man, 37 years old, and I live alone in my own house.
I am not comfortable having kids spend time in my house without other adults present, preferably a parent <sup>[1]</sup>.

So far I've been able to shut down the requests by stating that I don't have the time for it.
But I want to shut this idea down for good.

To clarify: He's more than welcome to come and play, I enjoy sharing my interests with anyone like minded. But not kids alone, even if I have known them their entire life and is a close friend of the family.

**How can I explain this to the boy, preferably in a way that won't make him sad or feel that I'm rejecting his friendship in general.**

> **Update (about a month after posting the question):** The situation has now been resolved.
>
> He visited me with his mother and sisters a few weeks ago, to watch a movie and play som Virtual Reality games.
>
> As expected, he again asked if he could stay after the others left, and spend the night.
>   With his mother present in the conversation, I told him that he could of course stay as long as he wants, as long as one of his parents are there as well.
>   He looked to his mother and asked if he couldn't just stay alone, ensuring it would of course be fine.
>   Fortunately she agreed with me, and stated that a parent should always be present, and since I'm not a parent, it just wouldn't work out without her staying as well.
>   He accepted that with a bit of a frown, but the frown quickly vanished.
>
> They visited again this weekend, and we all had a great time - and an  important detail: No request to spend the night this time!
>
> Success! **:-)**

<sub>[1]: Being in charge of the kid is probably the largest part of what I don't like about that situation. I just don't know how to behave around kids alone. I feel on edge, constantly overthinking everything I do. Also to some people it might seem weird that an adult living alone has other people's children spending time unsupervised - I don't want anyone to have the opportunity to think something wrong might be going on in that situation. I know it's a bit paranoid, and frankly it's not the main reason. But it's a part of the uncomfortable feeling. I'm a bit introverted, and sometimes I have a hard time expressing my emotions. And I find kids difficult to 'read' sometimes.</sub>

Comment: Are you neighbors? Walking distance? Is there any sort of drive involved to act as a barrier?

Comment: There's a 30 minute drive between our houses, mine is in an urban environment, though in a rather small town. I have neighbors on 3 sides of the house, about 30-50 meters away each. All neighbors are elderly ladies, all pensioners whom stay at home all day, gossiping.
They have no way of knowing what goes on in my house, all they can see if who arrives/leaves and when. I park in a closed garage, but guests park out front, so it's usually rather obvious when I have visitors.

Comment: It's not the "environment" that I think is relevant (old neighbors and urban environ - although that's good info) - it's the distance that's between you and said 12 year old. Most kids these days aren't allow to walk "miles" and a 30 minute drive in an urban environment is 20-30 miles, ballpark guess. I'd not expect my kid to stay anywhere not directly related by immediate family - and not at a babysitters. It basically says random "HEY NEIGHBOR!!!" visits aren't an issue. - it also explains why visits without mom would basically lead into a "can I stay" question, since 12 can't just walk home

Comment: His mother would be okay with it, I'm sure. I'm the one who doesn't like the idea. His mother senses my hesitation though, and has thus not suggested a sleepover herself. And yes, the distance is quite far, about 20 minuttes of the trip is on the highway, it's two different small towns we live in. No option for him to bike home, nor is the bus an option (it would take about 2,5 hours to get home by bus).

Comment: **Please don’t write answers in comments.** It bypasses our quality measures by not having voting (both up and down) available on comments, as well as having other problems [detailed on meta](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1644/31). Comments are for clarifying and improving the question; please don’t use them for other purposes.

Comment: There seem to be two different problems here. The first is the one that you're asking about how to say no to a kid. The other one is about you being worried about the gossiping neighbors (which is definitely the root cause for at least some of your discomfort). I think both deserve an answer (or perhaps a reply) but the question as stated will only get answers for the first of the two problems...

Comment: @Jasper I see your point. The gossip part doesn't really worry me though, since shutting down the idea of spending the night alone, should eliminate any gossip I can't handle - since there won't be any potentially suspect situation to gossip about. Also, it's a minor part of the situation - the major issue is putting a stop to this idea of a sleepover at my place.

Comment: You seem to be worried enough by it to change your behavior over it. (When I say "the gossiping", I actually mean it a bit broader, including the idea that people might consider it strange and the whole bit about overthinking, which also seems to stem from what people will think.) So yes, saying no to the kid will solve the direct problem at this moment and you have every right to it and there are good ways to do this in a way that the kid understands. However, I think in the long run, the other problem is something that you should also address for your own good. But that's just my opinion.

Comment: @Jasper That's a general issue affecting all males who're ever in contact with children, especially alone. There is no available solution to this issue, other than a change of attitude in the society in general. That's not something I can handle, so I won't spend energy trying to solve that (to me) unsolvable issue.

Comment: Or is it an issue with how you perceive society to be? Probably bits of both. I'll leave it at that, though, as comments aren't for extended discussions.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

He's a kid. Treat him like a kid. That means being explicit about your boundaries.

> **Kid**: "Can I stay the night? I want to play some more on the VR tomorrow!"
>   **You**: "No. I'd rather you don't stay here without one of your parents around. You're free to come again next time with your mom/dad to play with the VR some more."

Sure he might be a bit upset that he doesn't get what he wants. (He might even fake being upset to manipulate you into changing your mind). But that's OK.

Just set your boundary; be clear about it any time he asks and he'll learn that he'll just have to be happy about the time he **does** get to spend with you playing on your awesome VR setup.

---

Besides clearly setting the boundary with the boy, also talk about it with his mom. Just kindly explain to her what you are okay with so she can tell her son the exact same thing you do: That he's welcome to play anytime, as long as it's along with a parent (and no sleepovers).

Despite kids telling you otherwise in an attempt to get what they want, in general they do like having clear boundaries. (If you don't believe this, feel free to check out any question on [parenting.SE](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/), I'd bet you at least 90% of the good answers tell you to just set a clear boundary and stick to it).

Comment: Good point. I just don't like disappointing people, especially not kids. But I suppose that a once-and-for-all disappointment on this subject, might be better than several future rejections. He's just so enthusiastic about it, so I feel bad for rejecting him.

Comment: Do you have a lot of experience dealing with kids? Based on what I've seen, I can't imagine that telling a kid "I'd rather" is likely to go well (because, taken literally, you're stating your preference, not firmly saying no). Even to an adult that would hardly be clearly setting your boundaries. What's wrong with simply "You can't"?

Comment: @NotThatGuy I have plenty of experience with my nieces/nephews, babysitting, ... but I'm not native english. The exact wording depends mostly on how you usually interact with said child and I don't think it matters too much for my answer to the question here. Feel free to adapt it to the situation you're in. You're probably right that the wording I used here may be too soft for a 12 year old in general, but given that OP has a friendly status with the kid already I'm expecting a gentler "I feel" aproach would probably be hard enough to convey what the expected boundary is here.

Answer (score 15):

*Please tell me if I've got this right, not completely sure if I've interpreted your question correctly but I've tried my best*

I understand where you're coming from. It can be awkward having a child over without their parent(s), especially should someone see them arriving at your house and spending the night when they know that you live alone - it just looks weird to people. You could be the most trustworthy human on the earth and it's still a strange thing to have a friends child stay the night, no matter how close you and said friend are.

If I were you I would explain myself to my friend, why you would prefer if her son just came over for a few hours to play and then went home again, putting emphasis on the fact that **he is welcome any time to play**, just **not to spend the night**. If she says that she's okay with him staying the night tell her that that's fine and you're delighted to hear that she trusts you enough to have her son over for a night, but you **aren't** okay with him staying over because you don't want things to be misconstrued should anyone else see or whatever your reasons may be. If she's that good of a friend to you, she will understand and you can either let her explain it to her son or you can sit down and explain it to him together. He may feel a little sad over it but he'll come around quickly, kids are great like that - good luck and I hope this helps!

Comment: You got it right, I find it weird and uncomfortable having kids in my house unsupervised by other adults. Even if I do have a guest room he could spend the night in. Thanks for your answer, I think I'll talk to him (and his mother if she's with him) next time I visit them and he asks to spend the night at my house.

Answer (score 9):

You should tell about this situation to his mother, and then, when he'll ask you again, reply with:

> You should ask your mother.

At this point, his mother will tell him "no", giving him a reasonable explanation if she consider it necessary.

I think it's correct that it's his mother to be the one that educates him and denies this request, she can take this as an opportunity to teach him how to behave with other people and what is a reasonable question or not.

Comment: Interesting idea. I'll keep it handy as a backup plan, in case he won't listen to reason when I tell him no next time :-)

Comment: but what if the mother says yes?

Comment: @superstar Ask her to not to?

Comment: @Crowley: That's asking the mother to either lie to her child (by answering *"Yes"* to *"Do you mind if I spend the night at Gersten's house?"*, even though she personally might not mind) or to confuse her child (by honestly answering *"Gersten does not want you to, even though he told you that you just have to get my permission."*), both of which are not OK in my opinion.

Comment: @Heinzi She might not mind if her kid sleeps *elsewhere*. But the question is about sleeping at *Gersten's*. Gersten do mind it, ergo his friend should mind as well. Therefore it is not a lie.

Comment: @Crowley: So what should the mother answer if the kid asks "Why?".

Comment: To use this, you would, of course, have to have spoken to the mother beforehand to make sure she's "on message". @Heinzi it doesn't necessarily mean the Mother has to lie. Obviously if the child asks "_Can I..._", then she can answer "_No_" truthfully (he can't because the OP doesn't want it); but even if he asks "_Do you mind..._", then she _can_ still reply "_No_"... the mother may not mind if the person concerned didn't mind, but because they (the OP) _does_ mind, and the mother doesn't want to put him in an awkward position, she does mind _in this case_,

Comment: (And depending on the "maturity" of the child, she can decide how much (or not) of the above to explain).

Comment: @TripeHound: I agree that there are "creative ways around this". Nevertheless, it puts the mother in a uncomfortable situation (at least I would find it uncomfortable, YMMV), just so that the OP can avoid being in an uncomfortable situation himself. I think that's not a nice thing to do.

Comment: @Heinzi I'm not saying it's the _best_ answer (and the "_At this point is his mother's "fault"_" part isn't the best wording), but advantages include **(a)** it's probably easier to explain to the mother why the OP is uncomfortable than it is to the child, and if the mother _isn't_ uncomfortable being in that situation, then **(b)** the mother is the "single point of contact" for setting the child's boundaries (consistency). Finally, **(c)** the mother should be in a better position to decide whether a simple "_no_", or "_no because..._" is right for her child.

Comment: I did answer this from mobile, I reworded the answer to look less harsh (maybe? lol)

Answer (score 1):

You've got fine answers already, but I'd like to add, that **you are not paranoid at all**.
I'm actually surprised you will be alone in your house with a kid in the daytime.
When we have had other peoples kid(s) sleeping in our house, I'd always made sure at least my wife or one parent to the kid was staying overnight as well.
If a kid woke up in the night, maybe crying because of a nightmare or similar, it's my wife (or overnighting parent) who must take care of it.
As a man, I'd never go alone into an overnighting kid's bedroom.
I am also never alone with a kid in a room anyway, not even in the daytime. At least the door must be wide open, and I want to be sure other adults are nearby.

This sounds paranoid, but it is not much different from 'always wear your seat belt when driving', or 'never go back to a piece of fireworks that didn't go off'.
It might go well 99 out of 100 times, but the one time something goes wrong, it can destroy you.

Comment: Actually I don't have kids in my house alone, not even in the daytime, as mentioned in my question: `I am not comfortable having kids spend time in my house without other adults present, preferably a parent.`. Though I can see how  `not comfortable` could be read as `I'll allow it, but I don't like it` - that is not the case, I don't allow it to happen. Which is why I want the requests for a sleepover to stop.